# Regex issues in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having issues getting data from a text file using Ruby. I've opened and read the file, and replaced all of the newlines with '%'s (because newline seems to cause problems), but when I try to call scan on the string, it doesn't parse the way I want it to. I'm sure this regex is way uglier than it needs to be, but here's what it's doing: http://rubular.com/r/JNgleGA5bd

The file has a numbered list, and since the formatting is consistent, I wanted a regex to grab each item on the list. In the snippet I include, it should have grabbed everything before "2.(tab)If "OTHER" boat manufacturer,"

Here's a sample of the string:

> "1.    What make is your boat?%%   [- Select One -]%%Var. 1: Code = A2_asdfw, Name = A2_WhatMakeIsYourBoat%%Type = Category%%Template = Standard Category%%Cat. 1: Code = 339, Name = NONE%%Cat. 2: Code = 3, Name = asdfg%%2. If "OTHER" boat manufacturer, please describe here:%***_*__*_*__*_*___**%%  Var. 1: Code = A154_asdf, Name = A36_asdfg%%Type = Literal%%Template = Standard Literal%%Maximum Length = 20 characters%%"

Here's my regex:

```
([0-9]+\.\t[\/0-9a-zA-Z\s,"()'-]+[%\t?:].*?)[0-9]+\.\t[\/0-9a-zA-Z\s,"()'-]+[%\t?:]
```

Comment: What is span? Don't expect us to click the link to see what you have. Don't expect us to be generous for your laziness. Write the relevant code here.

Comment: Still don't know what you're trying to do. Just getting the part of the text before `2. If...`? If so, `.*?(?=2\.)` will do.

Comment: Same here. Is this the desired result? http://rubular.com/r/GRBXUIqISV ... if so, I could explain a bit in an answer.

Comment: I explained myself really terribly. Basically, the file is a numbered list, and I want to grab each item. The problem is that there are numbers and symbols inside each item (thus the butt-ugly regex), and it doesn't seem to be stopping where I want it to.

Comment: @m.buettner Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks so much! I don't understand it all, but I think I can figure it out if I stare at it for a while.

Comment: I suggest you don't replace newlines with %, it will allow for a more elegant regex; can you give a sample with newlines instead of % ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each entry starts with the pattern "digit-period-tab", you can use this regex:

```
[0-9][.]\t(?:(?![0-9][.]\t).)*
```

[Working demo.](http://rubular.com/r/GRBXUIqISV)

Here is some explanation:

```
[0-9]          # match a digit
[.]            # match a period - same as "\.", but more readable IMHO
\t             # match a tab
(?:            # open non-capturing group. this group will match/consume single
               # character, that is not the beginning of the next item
  (?!          # negative lookahead - this does not consume anything, but ensure
               # its contents canNOT be matched at the current position
    [0-9][.]\t # check that there is no new item starting
  )            # end of negative lookahead ... if we get here, the next character
               # still belongs to the current item; note that the engine's
               # "cursor" has not moved
  .            # consume an arbitrary character
)              # end of group
*              # repeat 0 or more times (as often as possible)
```

[More information on lookarounds.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

If your items can go beyond number `9` (i.e., have multiple digits), simply add a `+` after both `[0-9]`.

Comment: Also, I took user2103316's advice and kept the newlines. The regex I ended up with is /([0-9]+[.]\t(?:(?![0-9]+[.]\t).)*)/m, since there are numbers higher than 9, and it's working perfectly!